# Simple Tip Calculator

Tags: swift, calculator, cocoa

This is something I put together recently, and I thought I would see if anyone had any recommendations for modification of this short implementation of a tip calculator.

The calculator uses a `UISegmentedControl` to switch between tip percentages of *10%*, *15%*, and *20%*. I have also added images of the interface under the source code.

Please let me know what I'm doing right and wrong, and if there is anything I can do to improve my code.

---

```
class TipViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var amountTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var tipLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var totalLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet var segmentedControlCenterYConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var tipLabelBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer!

    // Whenever the value of subtotal has been assigned, call updateTotalAndTipLabels().
    var subtotal: Double? {
        didSet {
            updateTotalAndTipLabels()
        }
    }

    // Based on the segementControl's selectedSegmentIndex, assign the appropriate tip percentage.
    var tipPercentage: Double {
        switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            return 0.10
        case 1:
            return 0.15
        default:
            return 0.20
        }
    }

    // A decimal styled NumberFormatter that allows up to 2 decimal places.
    let numberFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let nf = NumberFormatter()
        nf.numberStyle = .decimal
        nf.minimumFractionDigits = 0
        nf.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        return nf
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tapGesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))
    }

    func updateTotalAndTipLabels() {
        if let subtotal = subtotal {
            // Calculates the appropriate tip based on the selectedSegmentIndex of the segmentedControl.
            let tip = subtotal * tipPercentage

            // Updates the tipLabel.
            tipLabel?.text = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(floatLiteral: tip))

            // Updates the totalLabel to include the subtotal + the tip amount.
            totalLabel?.text = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(floatLiteral: subtotal + tip))
        } else {
            // If subtotal is nil, set the text of both the tipLabel and textLabel to their initial states, "0.00."
            tipLabel?.text = "0.00"
            totalLabel?.text = "0.00"
        }
    }

    // Whenever the keyboard resigns first responder, animate a couple constraints so that the segmentedControl and the tip Label and TextField is shifted into their inital states.
    func dismissKeyboard() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0) {
            self.segmentedControlCenterYConstraint.constant = -8
            self.tipLabelBottomConstraint.constant = 16
        }

        amountTextField?.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    @IBAction func subtotalFieldEditingChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
        // If the value passed is convertible to Double, set it to subtotal, otherwise assign 'nil' to subtotal.
        if let text = textField.text, let value = Double(text) {
            subtotal = value
        } else {
            subtotal = nil
        }
    }

    // Whenever a segment is tapped, call updateTotalAndTipLabels() to assign the appropriate tip and total amounts.
    @IBAction func calculateTip(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        updateTotalAndTipLabels()
    }

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        // Return false if user attempts to input invalid characters.
        guard string.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "1234567890.").inverted) == nil else { return false }

        // Allow user to proceed with their input request if nil is returned when attempting to find the range of the string "."
        // in amountTextField?.text and the attempted input is not "."
        return textField.text?.range(of: ".") == nil && string.range(of: ".") == nil ? true : false
    }

    // Whenever the keyboard becomes the first responder, animate a couple constraints so that the segmentedControl and the tip Label and TextField is shifted vertically up.
    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0) {
            self.segmentedControlCenterYConstraint.constant = -72
            self.tipLabelBottomConstraint.constant = 72
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

---

**PICTURES**

*note: These images are only provided for a better understanding of the actual implementation.*

*Picture of the initial interface*

[image]

*Picture of the interface with `amountTextField` as firstResponder and sample input data*

[image]

*Picture of the interface without `amountTextField` as firstResponder and sample input data*

[image]

Comment: if you respect SOLID then  your more clean .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add access level annotations (private/public)
- `UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0) {
          self.segmentedControlCenterYConstraint.constant = -8
          self.tipLabelBottomConstraint.constant = 16
  }`

  This won't animate. You shall call `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` inside animation block.
- You can abstract away tip calculation in separate class/struct. And make available tips as an input for this view controller.
- You can improve `NumberFormatter` with `nf.numberStyle = .currency`
- You can use Keyboard notifications instead of `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` to change screen layout. This will allow you to use animation options the same as keyboard uses (see `UIKeyboardWillShow` `UIKeyboardWillHide` and `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey`, `UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey` etc.).